# Sorting PHP array so that duplicate values are next to each other

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, duplicates

Using PHP I have this array:

```
[0]: John
[1]: Brian
[2]: Julia
[3]: Adam
[4]: Brian
[5]: Jonathan
[6]: Amanda
[7]: Julia
[8]: Nathan
```

I want to sort the array so that the order is as close to the original as possible, but with duplicates stacked, creating the following array:

```
[0]: John
[1]: Brian
[2]: Brian (duplicate value moved from index 4)
[3]: Julia
[4]: Julia (duplicate value moved from index 7)
[5]: Adam
[6]: Jonathan
[7]: Amanda
[8]: Nathan
```

I'm assuming that it's a matter of nested foreach loops, but I'm unsure how to apply unset() in a nested foreach loop.

EDIT: Since i probably didn't explain it very well I want to keep the duplicates in the array. I do not want to remove the duplicates.

Comment: Do you want to remove the duplicate or leave it?

Comment: Could you also post the code that you're currently having?

Comment: Duplicate it. I don't want to delete the duplicated values, just stack them together.

Comment: So really, you are not even sorting. What you are doing is moving the second and later duplicates to right after the first found value.

Comment: Why is the last Brian left alone and not moved?

Comment: @Dale Mistake on my part. Fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using `array_shift`, `array_intersect` and `in_array` functions:

```
$arr = [0=> 'John',1=> 'Brian',2=> 'Julia',3=> 'Adam',4=> 'Brian',5=> 'Jonathan',6=> 'Amanda',7=> 'Julia',8=> 'Nathan'];

$size = count($arr);
$i = 0;
$result = [];
while ($i < $size) {
    $el = array_shift($arr);  // current value
    if (!in_array($el, $result)) $result[] = $el;
    $dups = array_intersect($arr, [end($result)]);  // finding duplicates
    if (count($dups)) $result = $result + $dups;    // adding duplicates to "stack" if exist
    $i++;
}

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => John
    [1] => Brian
    [2] => Brian
    [3] => Julia
    [4] => Julia
    [5] => Adam
    [6] => Jonathan
    [7] => Amanda
    [8] => Nathan
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the most efficient solution, but works:

```
function dupsort(array $input)
{
    $output = array();
    $moved = array();
    foreach ($input as $key => $val)
    {
        if (isset($moved[$key])) {
            continue;
        }

        $moved[$key] = true;
        $output[] = $val;

        foreach ($input as $dupKey => $dupVal) {

            if ($dupVal!==$val) {
                continue;
            }

            if (isset($moved[$dupKey])) {
                continue;
            }

            $moved[$dupKey] = true;
            $output[] = $dupVal;
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It works, just tested.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    for ($j = $i; $j < count($array); $j++) {

        if ($i < $j && $array[$i] == $array[$j]) {
            $insert = array($array[$j]);
            unset($array[$j]);
            array_splice($array,$i,0,$insert);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to offer a slightly more resource friendly solution:

```
  function dupsort($data) {
    $result = [];

    foreach($data as $word) {

        // remove all matches of the current word from the source
        $before = count($data);
        $data = array_filter($data, function($x) use ($word) {
            return $x !== $word;
        });

        // add the word to the output as many times as it got removed from source
        $newCount = count($result) + $before - count($data);
        $result = array_pad($result, $newCount, $word);
    }

    return $result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [the `sort` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php).

```
$a = array("a", "b", "c", "a");

sort($a);
var_dump($a);
```

Result is:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "a" [1]=> string(1) "a" [2]=> string(1) "b" [3]=> string(1) "c" }
```

Comment: I thought this at first but it's not quite what OP is looking for

Comment: Are you saying OP wants those "(duplicate value moved from index 4)" as part of the result?

Comment: @FredericoSchardong Yes! That is exactly what I want as part of the result

Answer (score 0):

Use just one loop to create a reduced lookup map of the first occurrences of each unique value as well as an ordering array which will hold the earliest index of each value.

Then call `array_multisort()` to sort the original array by the ordering array.

No iterated function calls are written.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/OCpQv))

```
$order = [];
foreach ($array as $i => $v) {
    $lookup[$v] ??= $i;
    $order[] = $lookup[$v];
}
array_multisort($order, $array);
var_export($array);
```